# Travis CI: branch filters in build matrix items

Tags: travis-ci

We are wondering whether there is any way to add filters to Travis matrix items. In our particular case, we wish to run certain jobs only on specific branches.

The following example would be an ideal way for configuring this scenario, however it doesn't seem to work:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - env: BUILD_TYPE=release
      branches:
        only:
          - master
    - env: BUILD_TYPE=ci
      branches:
        only:
          - develop
```

As a workaround, we can exit from the build script immediately by checking the appropriate env vars (`TRAVIS_BRANCH`), but it is very far from ideal as launching the slave machine and cloning the repo takes a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Is per-branch `.travis.yml` an option?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Each branch can have its own `.travis.yml`, which looks like it fits your needs.

Comment: That sounds great. Where can I read about this feature?

Comment: [This section in the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Building-Specific-Branches)

Comment: How am I supposed to have a different `.travis.yml` file for each branch in an easily maintainable way? This seems like something that is really easy to break with branch merges.

Comment: There is a closed issue on travis-ci for this question here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2778 Looks like they don't want to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now achieve this with the beta feature [Conditional Build Stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/)

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: release
      if: branch = master
      env: BUILD_TYPE=release
    - stage: ci
      if: branch = develop
      env: BUILD_TYPE=ci
```