# TravisCI environment matrix options per branch

Tags: travis-ci

I have the following in my .travis.yml file.

```
env:
  matrix:
    - BROWSER=Chrome VERSION=53.0 PLATFORM="Windows 10"
    - BROWSER=Firefox VERSION=45.0 PLATFORM="Windows 7"
    - BROWSER=IE VERSION=11.0 PLATFORM="Windows 8.1"
    - BROWSER=Safari VERSION=9.0 PLATFORM="OS X 10.11" RESOLUTION="1280x960"
```

The above matrix executes four consecutive builds. I want to use all four for one branch, but only use a single one of those options for others. How can I accomplish this?

After spending a lot of time searching the web for a solution, I reached out here.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648230/travis-ci-branch-filters-in-build-matrix-items